# IE9 displaying inline-block divs incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I have a div with child divs that I'm trying to create a slideshow with. I have the child divs displayed `inline-block` and everything looks great except in IE<=9. In IE<=9 each `div.contentItem` is being displayed vertically.

I used `white-space: nowrap` and `inline-block` (instead of `float:left`) because more `div.contentItem` are asynchronously added and I didn't want to have to recalculate `div.content` width every time new elements are added. So, for that reason I would prefer to stay away from `float:left` unless there is a way to use float without having to specify a width.

**NOTE** I can't change the doctype as it's on a masterpage and used by many other pages within our cms. Too much regression testing.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
        <div class="contentItem">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 256px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 14px;
}

.contentItem {
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block !important;
    *display: inline;
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: why not change this page to not use the master for the doctype?  it would at least let you confirm that's the problem.

Comment: that is controlled by the cms administrators, so I can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `div.contentItem` to `span.contentItem`. Now the items display inline and no css change needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep your `white-space: nowrap` on your parent div, you should be able to use `float: left` on your children without having to define a width for the parent.

See this [Fiddle illustration](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/e6rbk/2/) I did for another post earlier.  It applies here too.  You can resize the result window to see that both versions where the `white-space` is set to `nowrap` (whether floating blocks or inline-blocks) they always stay on one row.

Comment: hmmm, I see what you're doing but it's not working for me. There must be another element that's causing the problem.

Comment: try `float`ing your parent `left` too ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/MnHQh/))

Comment: Saying _"not working"_ is not constructive.  Take the fiddle as provided here and break it... then come back and explain.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying that. Just giving quick feedback to Scrimothy

Comment: In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scrimothy/MnHQh/1/), I've only removed your `.contentItem display` properties and added `float: left` to both `.content` and `.contentItem`.  If yours still doesn't work like this, maybe it's the `.content`s parent that is breaking it?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I've updated the jsFiddle so that is my exact code. It's replicating my problem but haven't found out why yet, still experimenting

Comment: Can you post that broken fiddle?

Comment: it wasn't broken, I had an named the wrapper div wrong so all other css wasn't working. It's working now, well at least the fiddle is. It's got to be one of the parents. Slowly getting there... http://jsfiddle.net/MnHQh/3/

Comment: Great, looks like from your fiddle that this solved your problem.  Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your suggestion works in chrome perfectly but not in firefox or ie :(

Answer (score 0):

inline-blocks are sensitive when it comes to whitespace, if the content is exactly as wide as its parent it will probably break and go to the next line.. maybe you need something like this

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="contentItem">...</div><div class="contentItem">...</div><div class="contentItem">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

removing all the whitespace from around the inline elements should make them exactly the size you want them to be

Comment: I'd stay away from any scheme that depends simply on how you organize your code.

Comment: What @Sparky672 said.  *Especially* when using a modular CMS that's building pages from pieces scattered around the system.

Answer (score -1):

IE <= 8 doesn't fully support `display: inline-block`.
[Read here.](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)

Instead using `inline-block`, try to adopt this code to your slideshow:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ACNT/

Comment: but IE9 does and for some reason when the page loads it's going into IE9 Compat View and Document Mode: IE7 Standards

Comment: OP is having problems with IE9, and that table shows full support in IE 8+ anyway.

Comment: Probably based off my Doctype but I can't change that

Comment: its just a simple "click next/previous and go to next image". A div container that holds a content div that holds the child divs with images in them

Comment: inline-block is supported in IE8 and even your link says the same